# Online theme customizer missing details

Tags: themes

I have a very weird problem when I uploaded my theme from localhost to online. Look at pic for detail
[image: Other options are gone]

What I have done:

- Export database and import on server
- Upload every file to database
- Update wp-config

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a bit more searching, I came through a simple fix for my problem: **Clear cache and Refresh page**

I still don't get why it behaves this way. If anyone knows, please comment on this reply. Thanks